# How to override a default NESTED style defined in a 3rd party component

Tags: react-native

I have a 3rd party component i want to style, but I can't access the nested elements inside of it.

This is the component : 
https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

They talk about custmStyles but I don't know how to use this.
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0xU2.png)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClaraG. You should create your style objects, like in the original lib

> https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker/blob/master/style.js

For example, you can simply download the raw file from GitHub and put it in your project. Of course, you will do some changes in this styles ;)

Then you set your styles in props:

```
import YourCustomStyle from './style';

<DatePicker
   style={{width: 200}}
   date={this.state.date}
   mode="date"
   customStyles=YourCustomStyle
```

Comment: Thanks Yura! I simply added customStyles={styles} and it works perfectly.